# Происхождение слова "соль"

Tags: этимология, корень-слова

Вдогонку к вопросу о нотах.
Соль — Солнце — нота *соль*. Собственно, если верить приведенному мной в прошлом вопросе списку, название ноты и происходит от латинского названия Солнца.

А как быть с пищевой солью? Это название ведь похоже в разных языках (по крайней мере, в европейских, насчет остальных — не знаю).
Случайно ли совпадение? А если нет, то *какая связь между Солнцем и солью?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Между солнцем и солью никакой, хотя древний корень солнце похож - "солнь-. Самый корень "сол-" очень древний: почти во всех языках Европы солнце называется словами, произведенными от него: латинское "соль", французское "солей", немецкое "зоннэ"...

А вот соль по-латыни  звучало "саль", по-французски - "sel" ("сэль"), у
латышей - "салс", у древних готов - "салт"...

У Фасмера: соль по-латыни пишется  sāl, род. п. salis ср. р., а соль муз., "название ноты" из ит. sоl . Просто похожее произношение:

I, род. п. -и, ж., укр. сiль, род. п. со́ли, др.-русск., ст.-слав. соль , болг. сол, сербохорв. со̑, род. п. со̏ли, словен. sọ̑l, род. п. solȋ, чеш. sůl, слвц. sоl᾽, польск. sól, род. п. soli, в.-луж. sól, sel, н.-луж. sol.

И.-е. основа на -i ср. рода, др.-лат. sаlе, арм. аɫ, тв. ед. 2. Родственно др.-прусск. sаl (по мнению Брюкнера , заимств. из слав.), лтш. sā̀ls "соль", лит. sólymas "рассол", лтш. местн. н. Sаlасе, лат. sāl, род. п. salis ср. р., греч. ἅλς м. "соль", ж. "море", др.-ирл. salann, гот. salt "соль", тохар., далее сюда же соло́дкий, со́лоть

солъ-солн-солон(ст.-слав.сланъ)-солоный(солонец, солонина)

СОЛЬ. Общеслав. индоевроп. характера. Интересно, что корень тот же, что в сладкий.

http://newslab.ru/article/139067/

Так что это разные корни.

Answer (score 3):

Происходит от индоевр. основы на -i ср. рода (*sal-), ставшей источником для др.-русск., ст.-слав. соль (др.-греч. ἅλς), русск. соль, укр. сіль (род. п. со́ли), болг. сол, сербохорв. со̑ (род. п. со̏ли), словенск. sọ̑l (род. п. solȋ), чешск. sůl, словацк. sоľ, польск. sól (род. п. soli), в.-луж. sól, sel, н.-луж. sol. Отсюда же др.-лат. sаlе, арм. аɫ, тв. ед. aɫiw. Родственно др.-прусск. sаl (по мнению Брюкнера, заимств. из слав.), латышск. sā̀ls «соль», лит. sólymas «рассол», латышск. местн. н. Sаlасе, лат. sāl (род. п. salis ср. р., греч. ἅλς м. «соль», ж. «море», др.-ирл. salann, готск. salt «соль», тохар. А sāle, В salyi, далее сюда же соло́дкий, со́лоть. Сюда же Хюбшман относит название реки Ώ ́Аʎυς (Малая Азия). В составе местн. нн. обозначало первонач. «соленый источник», ср. Солига́лич, Солика́мск, Сольвычего́дск. Отсюда же прагерманск.* saltan (ср.: др.-англ. sealt, англ. salt, нем. Salz и т. п.
Ни о каком солнце речь не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

"Соль" это трансформация солнечных лучей на земле, принявших такую форму, есть у северных народов редкая болезнь, когда нехватает солнечного света начинают поедать соль в больших количествах.